First event after window creation - XCreateWindow
I would like to perform some action when handling the first event after window creation - XCreateWindow. Events are obtained using XNextEvent function. I can use a bool variable to handle it but I wonder if there is a XEvent which is always sent first after a window creation ?

"The XCreateWindow function creates a window ... and causes the X server to generate a CreateNotify event.". Create your window and before doing anything else, wait for the event (e.g. via XIfEvent). See: https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#XCreateWindow

When you create a window with XCreateWindow (or XCreateSimpleWindow), there's really isn't a single specific XEvent that is guaranteed to be the first event received for that window. However, certain events does typically occur shortly after the creation (e.g., ConfigureNotify, MapNotify, and Expose), and from my observations it is usually ConfigureNotify to be the first event.
